# Using datetime from Rails in Phoenix with Ecto

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, datetime, ecto

I have a database created in a Rails application and now I want use this same database in a Phoenix application (using Ecto). The major problem at this time is with datetime values.

The Rails application show me things like this:

```
Tue, 06 Feb 2018 00:13:36 -02 -02:00
```

And the Ecto query on the same table show:

```
[{{2018, 2, 6}, {2, 13, 36, 22082}}]
```

Note the timezone lost.

The DB is schemaless on phoenix application and this is necessary.

So, I want keep the timezone information and convert the data to a more useful format for calculations.

Is there a way to do this?

Ecto ~ 3.0

Phoenix ~ 1.2.1

Rails ~ 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rails does not store time zone data in the database. All datetime values are stored in UTC. When you query a datetime field on an ActiveRecord object, it converts the output to the time zone set in your application.rb file using `config.time_zone =`.

Comment: Interesting! I found out this config and was already defined. But, I realise that doesn't matter this information wether I wasn't saving the correct timezone for all inputs (big country haha). So, this isn't more a problem by now, but I'll keep this post open for a while just in case more interesting answers. Thanks, @moveson